# What does "Data Source cannot be empty. Use :memory: to open an in-memory database" mean?

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite

I recently converted my SQL Server database into SQLite DB. But when I try to open my SQLite using `.Open()` it throws me this error:

```
Data Source cannot be empty.  Use :memory: to open an in-memory database
```

Edit: added connection string:

```
ConnectionString = @"Data Source=D:\XXX.db;Version=3";
connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Why do I get this? I converted the same SQL Server database to SQL CE and mySQL and I didn't get these errors.

Comment: please put the connection string in the question.

Comment: ConnectionString = @"Data Source= D:\XXX.db;Version=3;connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString); connection.Open();

Comment: Is that space significant after the = ??  Data Source= D:\XXX.db

Comment: sorry guys its my mistake .. at one place i have mentioned as"datasource" without spaces ..that caused the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a space after your data source: `Data Source= D:\XXX.db`. Also, in your copy/paste, there's no closing quote to the connection string. Here's a connection string that works for me for the testing tool:

```
@"Data Source=C:\Temp\Test.db3;Pooling=true;FailIfMissing=false;Version=3"
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I already figured that out and you can see that in my comment below the question

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error recently when I actually was trying to use the in memory version of SQLite.

I was setting up the connection as follows:

```cs
var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Filename=:memory:");
connection.Open();
```

And getting the error

> Data Source cannot be empty. Use :memory: to open an in-memory

I then changed it to this code, note the 'SQL' part is no longer capitalised:

```cs
var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");
connection.Open();
```

And now it works.

The working, non capitalised version is from the  Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection namespace where as the SQLite version is from System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection (I had version 1.0.113.6 referenced).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided a data source name, aka where the sqlite file exists.

Comment: I did ,refer my other comments

Answer (score 0):

Because your Data Source is empty. Add the Data Source paramater to your connection string. before opening the Sqlite database.

Comment: Its not empty .I had specified exact path dude.. connectionString = @"Data Source= D:\XXX.db;Version=3;   connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

Comment: Perhaps removing the space from the front of the `D:\` and close the connectionString with a double quote might help.

Comment: sorry guys its my mistake .. at one place i have mentioned as"datasource" without spaces ..that caused the problem. Thanks