# Sqlite "Data source cannot be empty"

Tags: c#, sqlite

I get the error "Data Source cannot be empty.  Use :memory: to open an in-memory database"

Here is my connection string:

```
// Get Current Users App Data
            string documentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath
            (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            string[] tempstr = documentsFolder.Split('\\');
            string tempstr1 = "";
            documentsFolder += "\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History";
            if (tempstr[tempstr.Length - 1] != "Local")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tempstr.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    tempstr1 += tempstr[i] + "\\";
                }
                documentsFolder = tempstr1 + "Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History";
            }

            // Check if directory exists
            if (Directory.Exists(documentsFolder))
            {
            //    return ExtractUserHistory(documentsFolder);

            }

            string connectionString;
            connectionString = string.Format(@"DataSource={0}", documentsFolder);
```

And here is my connection:

```
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039720/c-sharp-sqlite-what-is-data-source-cannot-be-empty-use-memory-to-open-an

Comment: You could simplify this a lot if you'd use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` - if you always need *LOCAL* instead of *ROAMING*. Also consider using [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781134) or at least [StringBuilder.Append](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds86a594) instead of concatenating strings in a loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error is given when the connection string is wrong.

In your `@"Data Source={0}"`
you must put Data Source instead of DataSource

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! And thank Google this was the 2nd result for that error message... I could have been hunting for this detail for quite some time.