# NHibernate throws an exception 'Data Source cannot be empty'?

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, nhibernate, in-memory-database

I'm a newbie to NHibernate and trying to get my first app working with NHibernate + SQLite - In memory DB.

so far, I've done the following,

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <reflection-optimizer use="true"/>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">"Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;"</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.release_mode">on_close</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Hibernate.cs**

```
public NHibernate.ISessionFactory Hibernate()
        {
            NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
            cfg.Configure(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "hibernate.cfg.xml"));

            cfg.AddAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

            return sessionFactory;
        }
```

Now when I call **Hibernate()** function, the following line throws an exception,

```
var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Exception : 
***System.ArgumentException: 'Data Source cannot be empty.  Use :memory: to open an in-memory database'***

I've been trying to fix this for quite some time now, I have tried with different connection strings, but I've had no luck. Any suggestions/guidance would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Data Source cannot be empty. Use :memory: to open an in-memory database" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039720/what-does-data-source-cannot-be-empty-use-memory-to-open-an-in-memory-databa)

Comment: @SeM, Thanks for the comment, I've looked into this link already, but they are using specific db file name, but I'm using in memory.

Comment: Are you sure hibernate.cfg.xml is being loaded?

Comment: @ikkentim, yes for sure, I checked this by commenting out the connection string and it has thrown 'missing connection string' exception

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there should be double quotes around the value of the connection string property in the configuration file.